# I got an error abour unsupported operand so how can i solve this?

Tags: python, input, operands

```
temperatureinkelvin=('please enter the temperature in kelvin')
temperatureincentigrade=temperatureinkelvin-273
print(temperatureincentigrade)
```

and this is my error:

```
 line 2, in <module>
    temperatureincentigrade=temperatureinkelvin-273
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified `temperatureinkelvin` as an input.
Try this:

```
temperatureinkelvin=int(input('please enter the temperature in kelvin'))
temperatureincentigrade=temperatureinkelvin-273 
print(temperatureincentigrade)
```